# Cloud Functions for Firebase - numChildren()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to get the number of children of a snapshot.

Inside the receipts are different receipts:

/receipts/{receiptid}/ -> receiptid, user (...)

```
let bookID = "book1" // e.g. -> String from another function

let ref = admin.database().ref("books").child(bookID).child("receipts");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot){

//get number of children of snapshot
let number = snapshot.numChildren(); //DOESN´T WORK -> ERROR

});
```

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean the value of `number` is not what you expect?  Is it zero?

Comment: no, in my firebase console only an error is given that says that numChildren() is not defined

Comment: That's odd.  I just ran your code in a cloud function without error.

Comment: I used let ref = admin.databaser().ref("books").child(bookID).child("receipts") .. does this change anything?

Comment: Edit your post to show the actual code producing the error.  The current code does not show how you define `bookID`.

Comment: See what result if you use some other property or method of `snapshot`, e.g. `console.log('key=', snapshot.key);`

Comment: works fine, the error is also not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

`numChildren` must be before the key, for example:

JSON:

```
{
    people { 
       name: "val", 
       age: "10" 
   }
}//people have 2 children.
```

therefore, to obtain the number of children you need:

```
firebase.database().ref().child ("people").once("value").then(snap =>
    console.log (snap.numChildren());
    //the return will be: 2
);
```